# GridView Column Width Issue C#

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I am trying to set the width of a column in a Gridview in C# and it is not working at all. I have tried to set the header style and item style via the following method:

```
GridView1.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
```

and similarly for the header style. None of this seems to be working. I see many forums online that people are having a similar issue but after looking for approx 1h30m I still could not find one that also had a solution.

There is also one stipulation - all of the columns in my grid are dynamic so it must be something that I can set programatically - not in markup.

I appreciate any help on this issue!

**EDIT:** with the help of Jon and through some other research I believe the issue is because I have defined no columns in the markup. However, I have not figured out how to resolve this. I cannot place columns in the markup because the table is generated using repeaters on the back end. If anyone has any insight into this please let me know.

Comment: question, why don't you state your columns in your grid view columns property?

Comment: @Kevin, he said he doesn't want to set them in the markup because they are dynamic.

Comment: you can bind it to a property in mvvm.

Comment: great thing about wpf it's extremely flexible to anything.

Comment: This question is not about wpf unfortunately, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: Correct - this is not about wpf. And I'm sorry but I'm unfamiliar with the term mwm.

Comment: @Zack - why not set the columns in your code behind?

Comment: @zack - are you aware of the fact your approach doesn't scale? Why an approach with CssClass and neat combination of external CSS' won't work for you?

Comment: @Tim the columns are set in my code behind

Comment: @Sander please explain. This approach was selected so that the table can use data from any table - not just bound columns declared in markup. With this approach it binds the columns in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I realized that because I was databinding my grid to a datasource, and because my gridview had the property of autosizing the columns, there is no way to set the width of the column afterwards. If you change that property to false, you should be able to programatically resize them.

EDIT: this is the markup you need somewhere inside your GridView markup:

```
<Columns>                                
    <asp:BoundField DataField="your_database_column" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="your_next_database_column" />
    ...                                           
</Columns>
```

Comment: thank you for the timely response. What is the name of the attribute that I must set to false. Do you happen to know? If not I'll start looking around for it!

Comment: It's not actually called autoresize, I believe it's called autogenerate columns. Set that property to false.

Comment: Are you databinding your grid?

Comment: Yes, to a SQL Server db table.

Comment: I think I know what it is, I specifically remember doing this. If in your GridView markup you don't have the <Columns> element, the program assumes there are no columns. However many columns you have inside your <Columns> element is how many columns the program thinks there are.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use markup because the gridview is generated using repeaters on the back end code. On the page I have a drop down list and the code generates a gridview based on the table name selected in the drop down list.

Comment: Could you do something like myGridView.Columns.Add(new BoundField("blah")) or something similar?

Comment: That is how I am creating them now, yes. But it isn't in the markup.

Comment: Hmm... not sure I know exactly what the problem is then.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting `GridView1.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);` ought to do it. The corresponding td should contain style="width:100px" when you do so. The header element's width need not be modified, as it's done so automatically.

Also set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` in your Gridview declaration.

Comment: if this doesn't work for you, could you try posting your gridview's declaration? It's likely you're overriding the width somewhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - that was the first approach I had tried as I assumed that would fix the issue.

Comment: That's strange. Could you edit your question and add the declaration markup as well?